# CSS hover effects & overlays

Tags: html, css

I have a picture with an transparent overlay on top of it. If i Hover above it, I want the image in the background to blur and the overlay to become opaque. Since both layers are on top of each other, only the opacity of the overlay changes when I hover it. How can I trigger the image in the background?

My attempt:

```
<a class="icon" href="nettebad.html" >
        <img src="./web/nettebad1.jpg" width="300" height="250" />
        <div class="overlay">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum...</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

.icon {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 23%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.icon .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 290px;
    height: 240px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    color: black;
}

.icon .overlay:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.icon img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the `:hover` behavior on the `.icon` element, and use the [descendant selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) to update the children (`.overlay` and `img`) styling:

change the children  styling when their parent `.icon` is hovered:

```
.icon:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}
```

Demo:

```css
.icon {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 23%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.icon .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 290px;
  height: 240px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  transition: inherit;
}

.icon img {
  transition: inherit;
}

.icon:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
<a class="icon" href="nettebad.html">
  <img src="http://data.whicdn.com/images/193303321/superthumb.jpg" width="300" height="250" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum...</h3>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Might be a nice touch to add this transition: .icon, .icon .overlay {
    -webkit-transition: all .420s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .420s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .420s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .420s ease-in-out;
transition: all .420s ease-in-out; }